# Looking for a pattern in a math riddle

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Looking to find a pattern but no idea how:

$12\mathop{\square}21 = 86$,

$13\mathop{\square}31 = 192$,

$14\mathop{\square}58 = 389$,

$14\mathop{\square}94 = \ ?$

Comment: The fact that it's about numbers doens't mean it's about mathematics. Unless your friend asked you for a multivariate lagrange interpolation or something, but I bet he didn't.

Comment: Thanks, what is it then? Is it cryptography? sorry if i posted it here.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is not clearly defined. One of infinitely many ideas is the ansatz

$$x\square y := x\cdot a +b+ c\cdot y$$

leading to 3 equations, which can be solved giving

$$a=\frac{892}{17}, b=\frac{-11153}{17}, c=\frac{91}{17}.$$

Now, what is $$14\square 94=?$$

Comment: The answer comes out to be $582+\frac{9}{17}$. Kind of skeptical about whether this is it though.

Comment: @2012ssohn Of course not! It's supposed to be in decimal form: 582.5294117647059...

Comment: Yeah, but it's symmetric: $582+\tfrac{9}{17}=\tfrac{9889}{17}$

Comment: $\frac{9903}{17}$, actually.

Comment: @2012ssohn only if you use the wrong value of $a$ which i just fixed :)

Comment: @flonk - in that case my answer would be $581+\frac{12}{17}$.

Comment: @2012ssohn let's agree on $581.7058823529412...$